# Windows 7 WAN access fails soon after restart but LAN works fine

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, timeout

My win7 (x64, pro) acts weirdly recently. At first glance it is another simple noob "My Internets are kill, pleas halp!" problem. Well, it might be, but I've never encounter such a behavior.

Internet is not working, but I can access and ping my gateway (192.168.0.1) freely. Then if I restart the adapter (turn it off and on via control panel), Internet access is restored, but it fails after a couple of seconds (it's quite random - roughly 10-120 seconds). After that it is broken again. I've got timeouts. It sometimes fixes itself, but fails again shortly.

What I've found:

- It is not a hardware problem (or not not only) - it is the same for cable and wifi. Also I've got Ubuntu on the same machine and it works fine.
- It is not router/modem problem - other devices (phones, laptops, raspberry) work fine.
- Wifi drivers are up to date
- It is not a DNS problem (ping 8.8.8.8 gives timeouts)

Pleas halp ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the TCP/IP stack:

Open "Command Prompt" with administrator privileges using "Run as Administrator"

Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:
`netsh winsock reset catalog`

Reset IPv4 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:
`netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log`

Reset IPv6 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:
`netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: How about flushing the DNS? From command prompt type: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: When it fails but you can still ping the router, have you tried power cycling the router to see if connectivity is restored?